# htaccess redirect rule for downloading a file and maintaining file name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some trouble with my rewrite setup. I have a file on my server that looks like this `ABC-7.1.2-3958693-BFHSJF.bin` and I want to have a redirect so that `/7.1.2` gets you to the file. That part is working fine, however I need to maintain the actual fine name when downloading. Because of the redirect rule, the file is downloading as `7.1.2`. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Here is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule    ^7\.1\.2$  ABC-7\.1\.2-3958693-BFHSJF\.bin [PT]
```

Comment: If it's possible to see your actual htaccess redirect rule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule    ^7\.1\.2$  ABC-7.1.2-3958693-BFHSJF.bin [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still downloads the file with the undesired name.

Comment: What is the desired name ? ABC-7.1.2-3958693-BFHSJF.bin ?

Comment: If it's `/7.1.2`: empty your cache or try with an other browser. If it's `ABC-7.1.2-39...` change `[L]` to `[R=302,L]`